# Handling cURL error inside a function?

Tags: php, curl

I've seen the documentation, and several tutorials. However I can't get my code work handling errors. I just want to print "Error.", whatever error is.

Here's my code without handling error,

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
} 

$page = get_data('http://....');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($page);
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

**EDIT:** The next one prints the default error message, but not mine.

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if($data === FALSE) {
        $msg = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        throw new Exception($msg);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
} 


try {
    $page = get_data('wrong-url');

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($page);

    $div = $doc->getElementById('cuerpo');
    echo $doc->saveHTML($div);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`curl_exec()`](http://de3.php.net/curl_exec#refsect1-function.curl-exec-parameters) will return false on errors. You can throw an Exception in this case:

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if($data === FALSE) {
        $msg = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        throw new Exception($msg);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: ok, but outside the function I'm using the "$data" returned by get_data() function, whether it's OK or false, how can I deal with that?

Comment: Please, look at my edit. I did what you've suggested, but keeps printing the default error message.